# Spline model with a constant

Tags: r, time-series, generalized-additive-model, splines

I'm working on a reproduction of a model and I am running into some issues with the wording of the model and implementing it into R. The model that I am working with is an Additive AutoRegressive model, nonlinear in this case. The paper mentions that the final model that they chose was a "Spline model with a constant and with two lags, where a B-spline base of order 3 and 25 knots was chosen." The package that they used to generate this model was the "mgcv" package.

That's the background now here's what I have so far. I have the following dataset,

| y | x.1 | x.2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.7 | NA | NA |
| 0.4 | 0.7 | NA |
| -0.2 | 0.4 | 0.7 |
| 0.5 | -0.2 | 0.4 |

Where I know the values of y, x.1 is the first time lag, and x.1 is a second time lag. I can put this data into R and create a model with the inputs that are listed as a spline model using the GAM function from the R package mgcv. Where I define k=25 knots, this can be changed to 2 since I only provide a small dataset, bs="bs" defines the B-spline method and s() is simply a smoothing function placement for both lags.

```
test2<- gam(y~ s(x.1, bs="bs", k=25)+s(x.2, bs="bs", k=25), 
            data=full_set_1)
test2
```

I then get the following output when I run the full dataset, which is what I expect however I'm having a bit of an issue in not understanding how do I define the B-spline base order of 3? And secondly, I'm also not certain by the wording of "Spline model with a constant" and how would I implement a constant to my model below?

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x.1, bs = "bs", k = 25, fx = FALSE) + s(x.2, bs = "bs", 
    k = 25, fx = FALSE)

Estimated degrees of freedom:
23.6 22.4  total = 46.99 

GCV score: 0.01041977
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume the "constant" just means the model intercept or constant term. The intercept/constant is implied in R's formula notation, but you can state it explicitly via

```r
m <- gam(y ~ 1 + s(x.1) + s(x.2), data = df, method = "REML")
```

but it isn't necessary to specify it explicitly as it is always included *unless* you suppress it with `0 +` or `- 1` added to the formula.

As for using cubic (order 3) B splines, this is the default, but you can specify this via the `m` argument. The default is `m = c(3,2)` which is a cubic B spline basis with 2nd order derivative penalty.

Comment: Hi Gavin,

Thanks for the reply, this makes more sense. For my own understanding, I did create a very similar model to what you have above with just a few extra parameters, provided below. Additionally, I did take a look at some of the parameters in more detail with ```fit=FALSE```. 

Thanks for the help, I'm certain now that I have the same model and just have to make some minor modifications to the data to replicate the result.
```test3<- gam(y~ s(x.1, bs="bs", k=25,m=c(3,2))+s(x.2, bs="bs", k=25, m=c(3,2)), drop.intercept = FALSE, data=full_set_1)```